# What is the best way to add the authenticated user to a related model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-events

What is the best way to add the authenticated user to a related model?

If I wanted to add the authenticated user as the author on a post model whenever a new post is created, what would be the best way to do it?

Currently, I have the following which does the job but it runs an extra query (i.e 1. Create post. 2. Update post with author_id).

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $post = Post::create($request->all());
  $post→author()->associate($request->user());
  $post→save();

  return new PostResource($post);

}
```

There must be a better way to do this. I was thinking of just adding all the attributes manually, with `$post-author_id = $request→user()→id`, and then calling `$post-save()`. However, I do not like the idea of having to manually write out all the other attributes of the post.

Another option I was thinking is by creating an event listener on the Post creating event. I do not know if this will reduce the need for an extra query.

What is the simplest solution?

Comment: If you really want to reduce the extra query burden then create a job and let the queue handle the extra burden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `create` method, you could simply create a new instance of `PostResource` and fill it with `author_id`. So it would be a bundled query.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $post = new Post($request->all());
    $post->author_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $post->save();

    return new PostResource($post);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can consider this on related model:

```
/**
     * Save auth user on create
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $userID = auth()->id();
            $model->author_id = $userID;
        });
    }
```